# Как добавить водяной знак на изображение

Tags: php

Никак не могу сделать добавление на изображение водяного знака.
Желательно, чтобы при загрузке изображения водяной знак накладывался и изображение сохранялось на сервере уже с водяным знаком.

Код загрузки изображения на сервер:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['Upload']) {
    $data = $_FILES['file'];
    $tmp = $data['tmp_name'];
    if (@file_exists($tmp)) {
        $info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)) {
            $name = "$imgDir/" . time() . "." . $p[1];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);

            // тут запрос на добавление данных о файле в базу

        }
    }
```

Как мне реализовать подобное?

Comment: Зачем вы один и тот же вопрос задаете по несколько раз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function watermark($file, $watermark) {

   if(empty($file) | empty($watermark)) return false;

     $wh = getimagesize($watermark);
     $fh = getimagesize($file);
     $rwatermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); 
     $rfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

      imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, $fh[0] - $wh[0], $fh[1] - $wh[1], 0, 0, $wh[0], $wh[1]);
      imagejpeg($rfile, $file, '80'); 
      imagedestroy($rwatermark);
      imagedestroy($rfile);

     return true;

}
// юзаем так
    $newfile = 'img.jpg';
    watermark($newfile, './copy.png');
```

Comment: А как мне сохранить изображение с наложенным знаком на сервер. просто на сайте изображения выводить мне надо примерно так `<img src="путь_к_картинке" class="imga" height="870" width="870">`

Comment: watermark($name, './copy.png'); добавь после move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы прокомментировали свой код. Советую прочитать это:
[Как написать хороший ответ?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: а как тогда будет выглядеть путь к изображению в переменной `$newfile` ?

Comment: причем тут $newfile? у вас путь в переменной $name